# Calculate time difference between current and future time

Tags: java, android

I want to calculate time difference in milliseconds from current time of a day(11 am , 1 october,2012) and time at midnight for the same day (11 pm 59 m 59s , 1 october , 2012.

I have tried this

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        cal.getTime().getTime() - today.getTime();
```

here today is the current date.

But when i print long values of cal and today , the time difference if of 86400 approx one day.

Comment: Use cal.set instead of cal.add

Comment: Using .set(), .add() or .roll() you need to call .get() to make the changes persistent. So adding a cal.get() between each add() would probably solve it.

Comment: ...from http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: Thanks guys , finally achieved it this way    cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DATE)+1, 0, 0, 1); cal.getTime().getTime() - today.getTime()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `cal.set()` instead of `cal.add()`

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);

long diff = cal.getTime().getTime() - today.getTime();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set your date to newly created Calendar instance..
And then compare it with current instance using `getTimeInMillis()`

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 9);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);

long difference = cal.getTimeInMillis() - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: Took it from the question OP posted.. He wanted it for October 1, just gave an example..